# how can i persist gitk font size in mac?

Tags: git, macos, gitk

I am using gitk in mac and font size is really small for me.
For a session I increase the font size by clicking in gui 
Preferences >> Fonts >> Changing all font size from 9 to 16
But this change is only valid for that gitk screen.

When I open a new gitk window font size default back to 9.
How can I persist font size to 16 so that everytime I open gitk I get my preferred setting?

This question is specific to Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working as it is, changes persist as well. I started gitk from intellij terminal. When I invalidated cache and restart intellij, my gitk started showing the changed fonts.

Comment: You can also verify that the changes were saved by checking the file `~/.config/git/gitk`. Some sizes like 16 are a bit too non-standard for the font selector UI.